# Java package naming

Tags: java, package, naming

Okay, so I'm wanting tips on how to pick a name for my Java packages.

I saw this post: [What package naming convention do you use for personal/hobby projects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292169/what-package-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-personal-hobby-projects-in-java) but this talks about personal projects.

What if for example I wanted to make an API Wrapper, and I develop with others on GitHub? I don't have a domain name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain-name-backwards convention is there to prevent name collisions. Two different companies with the same product name will have different namespaces so everything works fine.

If you don't have a domain then you need to choose a name that is meaningful to you and will not collide with anything else. That's OK; it just means very slightly more work for you to make sure that there isn't an existing product with the name you want, and there may be difficulties if there ever *is* a name collision.

You won't be the first to do this: the [JMockit library](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit) is all in the "mockit" namespace with no "com" or "org" prefix.

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. And also thanks for linking me to a library that does this.

Comment: JUnit *used* to do this as well: In JUnit 3, the package was `junit.framework`, in JUnit 4 it was changed to `org.junit`.

Answer (score 2):

The recommendation has always been to start with your domain name backwards, then the project name, e.g. com.mycompany.myproject, and continue on with submodules as necessary.

Comment: I don't have a domain name, should I use com.github.username.myproject?

Comment: If the project has a domain name and you can use it, sure.

Comment: @Languages: Yes, I just wanted to recommend this.