# How should I name a Java package?

Tags: java, github, package, sourceforge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What package naming convention do you use for personal/hobby projects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292169/what-package-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-personal-hobby-projects-in-java)

I am learning Java and have found a problem. I would need a domain name for my packages, but I don't have one. I wouldn't like to use my email address. So should I make an account on SourceForge or GitHub and use that? If so, which one is best? Or is there another, better method?
Thanks

Comment: Personally, I use `lastname.projectname`

Comment: I have read that question, but I was thinking of perhaps making a Bukkit plugin for Minecraft, something that others will use. I am now thinking of using GitHub. Is that a good method?

Comment: Why not just buy a domain? Every self respecting software developer should have one. They aren't exactly expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common naming scheme used is the following (`|` means or):

`country`| `org`|`com`.`name`.`applicationName`.`subpackages`

`Name` is either a company or your name. And after the `applicationName` you start all your subpackages (that is what I mean in the end) e.g. `util`, `ui`,`db` etc

For example if you are John Dave from England use `en.jdave.smartapp.ui.core.forms`. Or Marcus German From Germany: `de.mgerman.smartapp.ui.core.forms` etc

Comment: If you use that idiom, it implies that you own that domain. The OP does not own a domain.

Comment: Could I use a GitHub domain as my domain?

Comment: The idea is that this is a common structure to create a package name.Use for name your company name or your personal name.For example if you are John Dave from England: `en.jdave.smartapp.ui.core.forms`. From Germany: `de.jdave.smartapp.ui.core.forms`etc Also it doesn't have to be something universally unique unless you expect to be used by major companies across the world

Answer (score -2):

Generally Profession uses package name according to there reverse Site name 
For instance
**`com.site_name.applicaton_name`**

Comment: "I am learning Java and have found a problem. I would need a domain name for my packages, but I don't have one"