# Is this a valid java package name?

Tags: java, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What package naming convention do you use for personal/hobby projects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292169/what-package-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-personal-hobby-projects-in-java)

I made a google sites site name sites.google.com/sites/abc.(abc is not real name)

Would mcl.abc.sites.com.google.sites be valid for a package name.

EDIT: Whoops com.google.sites.abc.mcl

Comment: It'd be more traditional to use `com.google.sites.mcl.abc`, I think?

Comment: I am annoyed because this question has been marked as duplicate. The question of validity is something different than the question of conventions. There are two different words in english language - so why not use them properly? Please bear in mind that questions are not only interesting for the OP, but for others, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valid? Yes. Conventional? Probably not.

Java conventions typically recommend package names to be a website address (like your company's) in reverse, e.g. com.google.foo.

More on naming conventions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Comment: Thanks i didn't know about the /'s.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any name, but if its valid its about the criteria that you use, i recommend the following criteria:

1) avoid to use country.company.util (i work in a project that the company change 3 times of name, so you can see in the same project names like: com.companyname1.util, cl.companyname2.util, com.companyname3.util)
2) you can use naming like: dev.utils or apiname.commons.utils or any other criteria

Well, i hope this clarify your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Standard coding convention for packages in Java reverses the domain name.

Given your  example,

sites.google.com/sites/abc

```
com.google.sites.abc.mcl
```