# Using numbers as package names in java

Tags: java, package

I have checked the following posts already:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.2

and SO post:

[Is this a valid java package name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168968/is-this-a-valid-java-package-name)

and

[What package naming convention do you use for personal/hobby projects in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292169/what-package-naming-convention-do-you-use-for-personal-hobby-projects-in-java)

I tried creating a package like this:

```
package 01;
public class Test
{
// ...
}
```

When I compile I get this:

```
I:\code>javac 01\Test.java
01\Test.java:1: error: <identifier> expected
package 01;
       ^
1 error
```

**I am looking for syntactical correctness of the name not the convention.**

Is there a oracle/SUN reference that lists out the syntax for a package or does it follow the same rules as for variable names in java? May be a reference in the Java Language Specification saying package names follow the same rules as variable names.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8) links to identifier grammar that Java uses, which applies everywhere identifier is mentioned, including but not limited to package name. So `01` is definitely not a valid package name, since it's not a valid identifier.

Answer (score 16):

Found it:

> If any of the resulting package name components start with a digit, or any other character that is not allowed as an initial character of an identifier, have an underscore prefixed to the component.

In [JLS 6.1 Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)