# Build Failure in Stromcrawler 1.16

Tags: stormcrawler

i am using stormcrawler 1.16, apache storm 1.2.3, maven 3.6.3 and jdk 1.8.

i have created the project using the articfact command below-

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler -Darche typeArtifactId=storm-crawler-elasticsearch-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
```

when i run mvn clean package command then i get this error -

```
   /crawler$ mvn clean package
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO] 
  [INFO] -------------------------< com.storm:crawler >--------------------------
 [INFO] Building crawler 1.0-SNAPSHOT  
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ crawler ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/ubuntu/crawler/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ crawler ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ crawler ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ubuntu/crawler/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/ubuntu/crawler/src/main/java/com/cnf/245/ESCrawlTopology.java:[19,16] ';' 
expected
[INFO] 1 error 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  2.407 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-29T20:40:46Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile 
 (default-compile) on project crawler: Compilation failure
 [ERROR] /home/ubuntu/crawler/src/main/java/com/cnf/245/ESCrawlTopology.java:[19,16] ';' 
 expected
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
 [ERROR] 
 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
  following articles:
 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

i haven't edited pom.xml file.

Here is the content of the ESCrawlTopology.java file -

```
    package com.cnf.245;
    import org.apache.storm.metric.LoggingMetricsConsumer;
    import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;     
    import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;

    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.ConfigurableTopology;
    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.Constants;
    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.FetcherBolt;
    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.JSoupParserBolt;
    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.SiteMapParserBolt;
    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLFilterBolt;
    import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.bolt.URLPartitionerBolt;
    import 
    com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.DeletionBolt;
    import  
    com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.bolt.IndexerBolt;
    import 


 com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.MetricsConsumer;
        import 
 

com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.metrics.StatusMetricsBolt;
        import 
 

com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.AggregationSpout;
       import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.elasticsearch.persistence.StatusUpdaterBolt;
       import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.spout.FileSpout;
       import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.ConfUtils;
        import com.digitalpebble.stormcrawler.util.URLStreamGrouping;

     /**
 * Dummy topology to play with the spouts and bolts on ElasticSearch
 */
public class ESCrawlTopology extends ConfigurableTopology {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableTopology.start(new ESCrawlTopology(), args);
    }

    @Override
    protected int run(String[] args) {
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

        int numWorkers = ConfUtils.getInt(getConf(), "topology.workers", 1);

        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("ESCrawlTopology seed_dir file_filter");
            return -1;
        }

        // set to the real number of shards ONLY if es.status.routing is set to
        // true in the configuration
        int numShards = 1;

        builder.setSpout("filespout", new FileSpout(args[0], args[1], true));

        Fields key = new Fields("url");

        builder.setBolt("filter", new URLFilterBolt())
                .fieldsGrouping("filespout", Constants.StatusStreamName, key);

        builder.setSpout("spout", new AggregationSpout(), numShards);

        builder.setBolt("status_metrics", new StatusMetricsBolt())
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");

        builder.setBolt("partitioner", new URLPartitionerBolt(), numWorkers)
                .shuffleGrouping("spout");

        builder.setBolt("fetch", new FetcherBolt(), numWorkers)
                .fieldsGrouping("partitioner", new Fields("key"));

        builder.setBolt("sitemap", new SiteMapParserBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("fetch");

        builder.setBolt("parse", new JSoupParserBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("sitemap");

        builder.setBolt("indexer", new IndexerBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("parse");

        builder.setBolt("status", new StatusUpdaterBolt(), numWorkers)
                .fieldsGrouping("fetch", Constants.StatusStreamName, 
         key)
                .fieldsGrouping("sitemap", Constants.StatusStreamName, 
         key)
                .fieldsGrouping("parse", Constants.StatusStreamName, 
        key)
                .fieldsGrouping("indexer", Constants.StatusStreamName, 
        key)
                .customGrouping("filter", Constants.StatusStreamName,
                        new URLStreamGrouping());

        builder.setBolt("deleter", new DeletionBolt(), numWorkers)
                .localOrShuffleGrouping("status",
                        Constants.DELETION_STREAM_NAME);

        conf.registerMetricsConsumer(MetricsConsumer.class);
        conf.registerMetricsConsumer(LoggingMetricsConsumer.class);

        return submit("crawl", conf, builder);
          }
       }
```

i put com.cnf.245 in groupId and crawler in articfactId.

someone please explain what cause this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please paste the content of ESCrawlTopology.java? Did you set *com.cnf.245* as package name?

The [template class](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/1.16/external/elasticsearch/archetype/src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/java/ESCrawlTopology.java) gets rewritten during the execution of the archetype with the package name substituted, it could be that the value you set broke the template.

EDIT: you can't use numbers in package names in Java. See [Using numbers as package names in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016392/using-numbers-as-package-names-in-java)

Use a different package name and groupID.

Comment: hey @julien ! thanks for early reply. i have pasted the content of ESCrawlTopology.java in question.. kindly check what  is the issue.. thanks in advance